# The path must start with a '/' followed by one or more characters

Tags: tds

Using `Sitecore 10.1.2`

In my local machine, I have installed the instance and deployed the code and Sitecore items.
The solution uses TDS.

This is a multi-site project and one of the Site Grouping items is like this:

```
----field----
field: {475031D8-724D-463C-80B2-90839DD1AD98}
name: VirtualFolder
key: virtualfolder
content-length: 1
```

Meaning, there is no field value, but still the content-length is 1.
Could this be a reason. But isn't this a content item. Will the CMS still not load because of this? Even the login page isn't loading.

Anyways, I added `/` as the field value in the code for that item and then tried to do TDS `Sync with Sitecore`. But it throws an error saying:

[image]

That's because the CMS isn't loading.

Wen I browse my CMS, it throws this error:

> The path must start with a '/' followed by one or more characters.
> Parameter name: value
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred
> during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
> stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The path must start with
> a '/' followed by one or more characters. Parameter name: value
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: The path must start with a '/' followed by one or
> more characters. Parameter name: value]
> Microsoft.Owin.PathString..ctor(String value) +119
> Owin.MapExtensions.Map(IAppBuilder app, String pathMatch, Action`1
> configuration) +108
> Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Pipelines.Initialize.LogoutEndpoint.Process(InitializeArgs
> args) +244    (Object , Object ) +14
> Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +490
> Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
> PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> +236    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
> an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
> target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +216
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> +182    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass19_1.b__0(IAppBuilder
> builder) +93
> Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(IAppBuilder
> builder) +224
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +897    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +51
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
> +101    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
> +139    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
> context) +160
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +277
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +369
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
> of an invocation.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +111    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +719

**UPDATE:**

The Sitecore items were only pushed to master and I never published to web.
So, in the `Connectionstrings.config`, I pointed `master` also to the web database and now the CMS loads fine. (ofcourse without the content items).

Is there a way to fix this other than reinstalling the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try login without the identity server by following this approach.

To prevent Sitecore from redirecting users away from the `sitecore/login` page.

1. Patch the shell login page back to /sitecore/login, or request
   /sitecore/login with extra an URL parameter (?fbc=1).
2. Alternatively, patch the legacyShellLoginPage property of the
   InterceptLegacyShellLoginPage processor to some random value.

Either of these actions prevents Sitecore from redirecting users away from the /sitecore/login page. The SI server is configured as a regular external identity provider in Sitecore and it means you see its sign-in button on the /sitecore/login page. The caption is Go to login.

Refer to the Sitecore article for [Disabling Sitecore Identity](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html).

If this works, you can modify the item that is creating the issue and then revert it back.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect TDS installation or sync could be a reason then you can also try removing TDS stuff from your webroot.

Sitecore TDS installs a web service on the target Sitecore instance to communicate with Sitecore. The service is installed in the `webroot/_Dev` folder and a .dll is copied to the `/bin` folder. Try to search DLLs starting with `hedge` word and remove it.

Also as per your updated description, it looks like you lost content from the master db and that could be a potential issue. You can give it a try to create a master db using `Sitecore.Master.dacpac` file in a vanilla state. You will find this in `.scwdp.zip` file and then update the connection string to point newly created db.

Hope it helps!